# PyQt5: no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt

I'm building a PyQt5 application on Ubuntu 18.04, however, when I run my script, audio doesn't work and the console has this error when I import PyQt5.QtMultimedia

`defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"`

I've seen other problems similar to this, but their solutions didn't seem to work for me. I'm using PyQt5 5.11.2 installed from pip in a venv.

Solutions I tried:

1. `sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins`
2. `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia`

Comment: @eyllanesc Just tried that, doesn't appear to work for me, I still get the same error.

Comment: Then it returns `No module named 'PyQt5'`

Comment: Just tried running it outside my venv, it works now. Is there a way I can make this work inside a venv, or is that not possible?

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this issue? I'm having the same trouble.

Comment: Same error here. Have you found any solution (windows 10 python3.8)

Answer (score 0):

Try Running your python file globally as the pyqt5 module is installed in the global python not the virtual environment one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30815870)